# Handle http calls with errors inside a forEach - Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I'm writing a piece of code that cycles through an array and makes HTTP calls. 
Most of these HTTP calls are made to non-existent resources, but I don't know which ones. 
I'm currently using this piece of code:

```
    langs.forEach(lang => {
      this.http.get('assets/i18n/' + lang + '.json')
        .pipe(
          tap(data => console.log('server data:', data)),
          catchError(this.handleError),
        );
    });
```

The piece of code listed above shows me nothing in the console, when in reality a couple of data structures should be expected.
What **I would not expect** are error messages like:
`GET http://localhost: 4205/assets/i18n/[...] 404 (Not Found)`, but simply the results of the successful calls.
I wonder how one can only get good data structures, and filter errors within a cycle.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
`this.handleError` is taken from the angular documentation:

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message

    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}
```

Comment: What's `this.handleError`?

Comment: Maybe you are missing the subscribe to your service.

Comment: @KurtHamilton I edited the question. I got it from Angular's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make multiple calls in a for loop, I recommend that you use the `ForkJoin` **rxjs** operator, in addition to being more elegant, it is also more performing by making all the calls together.

```
const calls = [];
langs.forEach(lang => calls.push(this.http.get('assets/i18n/' + lang + '.json')));
Observable.forkJoin(calls).pipe(catchError(this.handleError)).subscribe(responses => {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `forkJoin` to run the multiple HTTP requests in parallel. If you want to handle errors on individual requests but still return responses for the others, you can add error handling to each individual request.

service.ts

```js
getLanguages(): Observable<any[]> {
  const observables = langs.map(lang => {
    return this.http.get(`assets/i18n/${lang}.json`).pipe(
      catchError(() => of(null))
    );
  });

  return forkJoin(observables).pipe(
    // remove empty values from the array
    map(results => results.filter(x => !!x)),
  );
}
```

You would then inject the service into your component and subscribe to the `getLanguages()` function.

component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getLanguages().subscribe(responses => {
    console.log(responses); // [ {}, {}, {}, ... ]
  });
}
```

Comment: Really excellent! If you also remove the outputs of this type from the console: `GET http://localhost:4205/assets/i18n/zu.json 404 (Not Found)` I'd say I approve of the answer!

Comment: Done :) It's a case of using the `filter` array function in an RxJS `map` to keep only the "truthy" values.

Comment: mmm this error appeared: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null` and the logs like: `GET http://localhost:4205/assets/i18n/zu.json 404 (Not Found)` have not disappeared...

Comment: Ok. Do you think there is no way to handle the errors and prevent logs?

Comment: OK, so two things... 1. I've just realised I put the `map` in the wrong place. Sorry! 2. I've just checked and I don't see errors in the console when using `catchError`. Can you check this stackblitz, and toggle between `true/false` in the `catchError` to either catch or throw. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mq2rkr

Comment: I saw. I did some tuning, but still I can't prune those logs...

Comment: Do you see console errors in my stackblitz when handling the errors?

Comment: yes, one as I expected:
`zone.js:3372 GET http://localhost:4205/assets/i18n/us.json 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: So I see the errors in Chrome, and I don't see them in Firefox. Looks like this is a browser thing that you can't do anything about. Why are you concerned about seeing 404 messages in the console? Anyone can open up the network tab and see failed requests there. As long as your app handles the errors, what's the problem? The only way to avoid a 404 is to not make the request in the first place.

Comment: ok, I'll settle. The goal of not showing logs is to keep a clean console.

Comment: @Memmo if you want to edit my answer based on linting errors, then A) mention it to me in comments, so I can adjust the answer if I think it is appropriate B) accept the answer if it has answered your question.

Comment: ok, forgive me, I didn't know this modus operandi. I wanted to redefine the answer, but in essence, the essential is there. :)

Comment: No problem. I agree that the `error` arg in `catchError` isn't used, so can be removed. `public` isn't required as an access modifier though. And I now see why you wanted to remove `baseUrl`, as it's a local query. Ultimately though, the details specific to your question aren't relevant to someone else with the same general problem.